# angular-ui's datepicker-popup doesnot shown when using in ngModal

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm integrating `datepicker-popup` of angular-ui with ngModal (https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngModal) but I have problem that datepicker popup only show one time, from second time it doesn't show anymore.

**EDIT:** It seems that after I click on a date to choose, `$scope.opened` is not updated to false, so from 2nd time it doesn't show. If I remove modal dialog just use datepicker then `$scope.opened` is correctly updated to false after choosing a date.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>AngularJS Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/ngModal/dist/ng-modal.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showMe()">Show Me</button>
        <modal-dialog show='modalShown' width="60%" height="500px" dialog-title='My Dialog'>
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" close-text="Close" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </p>
        </modal-dialog>
    </div>


    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngModal/dist/ng-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngModal']);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.modalShown = false;
    $scope.showMe = function() {
        $scope.modalShown = true;
    }
    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution for this problem.

Since `$scope.opened` is not set to false in modal dialog we can set this manually by using a `$timeout` function.

```js
$scope.open = function($event) {
        
        $scope.opened = true;
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.opened = false;
        }, 10);              
    };
```

```html
<input is-open="opened"
       type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
       ng-model="dt" />
```

Comment: (First Answer Review) Try to avoid asking questions in Answers.